# First If statement is true and else is true too Assembly language

Tags: if-statement, assembly, masm

So while i was studying , i had this question in assembly language.

```
Mov y,50
Mov x,20
.if x<50 
Inc y
.elseif x <= 100
Mov y,0
.endif
```

So my question is , since `X` is less than `50` , then It will increase `y`.

What happens then? Does it check if `X <=100 , move y,0` or will it ignore that part since it satisfies the first condition ?

Comment: You could try it yourself, assembling that code with MASM, then look at the disassembly to see what logic it really implements.  (But certainly it's going to follow the normal rules for else / elseif logic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ELSE-part is executed only if the first statement is FALSE, so if it is TRUE the code executes the INC and then goes after ENDIF.